# WooCommerce use shortcode in flat rate shipping class costs

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, shipping-method

In WooCommerce > Settings > Shipping > Shipping Zones > (the shipping zone) > flat rate, there are the inputs where you can put in custom shipping costs for shipping classes. In here, we can already use [qty] to finetune the results. Is there a way we can customize this to allow for custom shortcodes?

Say for example:

```
[qty] * 5 * [jwd_free_shipping_a]
```

Where `jwd_free_shipping_a` is a shortcode that checks to see if the entire pre-tax total of the cart is greater than, say, $100. If yes, it returns 0 (which would make it free shipping for this item in the above calculation), otherwise is returns 1.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, silly me, it looks like you already can use shortcodes there!

This is very helpful for setting up custom shipping rules!

Note: You can also pass `[cost]` in as a shortcode parameter, which returns the cost of the item in the cart, not the entire cost of the cart.

In my case, I ended up creating the shortcode as follows. Returning either a 1 or 0 helps me to potentially return free shipping based on a math equation I use (not the same one in the original post, but somewhat similar). I haven't seen any mention of this tactic in my search of Stack Overflow, so I'll leave this here as a reference.

```
add_shortcode('jwd_custom_shipping_a', 'jwd_custom_shipping_a_shortcode');

function jwd_custom_shipping_a_shortcode() {
  $return = 1;
  $cart_subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;

  if ($cart_subtotal > 89) {
    $return = 0;
  }

  return $return;
}
```